# Is there a keyboard shortcut in pycharm to navigate to the most recently active tab

Tags: pycharm

Many times while working in pycharm I have to switch between two different files or sometimes even between three different files frequently. Only way that I have been able to do this quickly using keyboard shortcut is to place these files are just sent to each other in the pycharm editor window and then use the keyboard shortcut "alt + left arrow" and "alt + Right arrow" to navigate back-and-forth.

However, sometimes these files are open in tabs with multiple other tabs in between. And then I have to keep on dragging the file tab is adjacent to each other so that I can navigate between them.
This is a common enough requirement, I was hoping that there would be a way to navigate between the most recently active tabs.

However, after searching on stack over.com and also in the pycharm documentation I could not find anything

I hope someone can help on this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ctrl+Alt+Left-Arrow (or Cmd+Alt+Left-Arrow) takes you back to the last cursor position (even if you did not edit this line but your cursor was there it will take you back).

Ctrl+Shift+Bakcspace (if youre a Mac user you may have to double check this) takes you back to Last Edit Location, regardless of file (i.e. it may take you to the same file, or another file).

Ctrl+Tab opens the Switcher. So a single Ctrl+Tab will jump you to the last viewed file, but not necessarily the last edited file. Ctrl+Tab,Tab the second to last viewed file; etc.

Ctrl+E opens a list of recently viewed files, listed in view order (most recent on top).

Ctrl+Shift+E opens a list of recently edited files, listed in edited order (most recent on top). So a sequence of  Ctrl+Shift+E, Enter  would take you back to the last edited file. (Also available via the menu as View > Recently Edited Files.) I do not believe there is an action to go back to the last edited file directly via a single shortcut.

Hope this helps! I am not sure if the most recent release has additions to these shortcuts I am unaware of.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I did know all of these commands earlier. I'm actually using speech recognition software because of my disability and it seems it was not working well with Ctrl + Tab. When you mention that Ctrl + Tab can take you to the last viewed file, I double checked the functionality of the speech recognition software and found an error in fixed it. Marking this answer as to resolving the query.  Thank  You